# OAuth authorization code grant using client libraries?

Tags: fusionauth

I have not been able to find support for the oauth2 login grant authorization code grant in the fusionauth client libraries.

I'm a little confused since it's the recommended login method according to https://fusionauth.io/articles/logins/types-of-logins-authentication-workflows

Is it correct that e.g. in the PHP or node.js client libraries this is not implemented or am I just not finding it?

Comment: Are you just looking for the call to the Token endpoint to complete the exchange for the access token after you've obtained the Authorization code?

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry for not being specific enough. In the meantime I have begun implementing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @mugeez for the clarification.

I made a commit to add a method `exchangeOAuthCodeForAccessToken` to the PHP client library to help you with this. If you can test it that would be great and let me know if it works for you.

https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-php-client/commit/fee9a29088f636e1c044cfbf18352e152588ad9d
https://packagist.org/packages/fusionauth/fusionauth-client#dev-master